# Using regex to extract a substring while excluding a certain phrase

Tags: regex, unix, grep

Say for the string:

```
test.1234.mp4
```

I would like to extract the numbers 
1234
without extracting the 4 in mp4

What would the regex be for this?

The numbers aren't always in the second position and can be in different positions and might not always be four digits. I would like to extract the number without extracting the 4 in mp4 essentially.

More examples:

```
test.abc.1234.mp4
test.456.abc.mp4
test.aaa.bbb.c.111.mp4
test.e666.123.mp4
```

Essentially only the numbers would be extracted. Hence, for the last example, 666 from e666 would not be extracte and only 123.
To extract I have been using

```
echo "example.123.mp4" | grep -o "REGEX"
```

Edit: test456 was meant to be test.456

Comment: So you want all blocks of *just* numbers that are surrounded by dots? In `test456.abc.mp4`, would you extract something?

Comment: what about the second one:test456.abc.mp4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer will fail on "test.e666.123.mp4" (print 666).

This should work

```
$ cat | perl -ne '/\.(\d+)\./; print "$1\n"'
test.abc.1234.mp4
test.456.abc.mp4
test.aaa.bbb.c.111.mp4
test.e666.123.mp4
1234
456
111
123
```

Note that this will only print the first group of numbers, if we have test.123.456.mp4 only 123 will be printed.

The idea is to match a dot followed by numbers which we are interested in (parentheses to save the match), followed by another dot. This means that it will fail on 123.mp4.

To fix this you could have:

```
$ cat | perl -ne '/(^|\.)(\d+)\./; print "$2\n"'
test.abc.1234.mp4
test.456.abc.mp4
test.aaa.bbb.c.111.mp4
test.e666.123.mp4
781.test.mp4
1234
456
111
123
781
```

First match is either beginning of line (^) or a dot, followed by numbers and a dot. We use $2 here since $1 is either beginning of a line or a dot.

Answer (score 5):

`cut` can make it:

```
$ echo "test.1234.mp4" | cut -d. -f2
1234
```

where

```
cut   -d'.'        -f2
      delimiter    2nd field
```

If you provide more examples we can improve the output. With the current code you would extract any `something` in `blablabla.something.blablabla`.

---

Update: from your question update we can do this:

```
grep -o '\.[0-9]*\.' | sed 's/\.//g'
```

test:

```
$ echo "test.abc.1234.mp4
test456.abc.mp4
test.aaa.bbb.c.111.mp4
test.e666.123.mp4" | grep -o '\.[0-9]*\.' | sed 's/\.//g'
1234
111
123
```

Comment: The question says "The numbers aren't always in the second position" but your solution assumes otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that's why I indicate *If you provide more examples we can improve the output*.

Comment: I think your example of using . as a delimiter is quite nice. Not exactly what I was looking for as I didn't know about perl until one of the answers appeared. But this would have been a creative/clever way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Po "(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "test.1234.mp4" | perl -lpe 's/[^.\d]+\d*//g;s/\D*(\d+).*/$1/'
```

or:

```
echo "1321.test.mp4" | perl -lpe 's/.*(?:^|\.)(\d+)\..*/$1/'
```

`p` is to print by default so that we don't need explicit `print`.
`e` says we have an expression, not a script file
`l` puts the newline

These will also work if you have a number at the first part of the name.

Comment: What does the -lpe stand for in here?

Comment: I like the idea of the one-liner, but I think it would be good to add an explanation of the parameters used. All in all, the idea here in SO  is not only to answer but to make the OP more independent with coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'\.' -lane 'print "$F[scalar(@F)-2]" if(/\d+\.mp4$/)' your_file
```

tested:

```
> perl -F'\.' -lane 'print "$F[scalar(@F)-2]" if(/\d+\.mp4$/)' temp
1234
111
123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
test.abc.1234.mp4
test.456.abc.mp4
test.aaa.bbb.c.111.mp4
test.e666.123.mp4

$ sed 's/.*\.\([0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/' file
1234
456
111
123
```